# Mobile Firefox addon development: window.BrowserApp.deck is null

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, fennec

I'm trying to write a simple little addon for Firefox Mobile, starting from [this skeleton](https://github.com/mfinkle/skeleton-addon-fxandroid). Ultimately I'd like to be running a bit of code against every new page loaded, which seems to be best accomplished by adding a "DOMContentLoaded" listener to every new tab, which fires when that tab loads a new page. To that end I need to detect new tabs, which is apparently in turn done by [adding a "TabOpen" listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Mobile/API/BrowserApp/deck) to the BrowserApp's deck.

Problem: At startup (but not when installing into an already loaded session), `window.BrowserApp.deck` is null for the only window. The documentation, what little there is, doesn't seem to suggest this is possible.

To test this yourself, download the skeleton linked above and add

```
window.NativeWindow.toast.show(window.BrowserApp, "long");
```

below line 48 of bootstrap.js, then build, install on Mobile Firefox, and restart. You'll see a toast reporting BrowserApp's properties, including 'deck: null'. (I'm also currently [hosting a copy](http://kevingibbons.org/sotest.xpi) of the extension you'll so obtain on my server, which is be much quicker to test: just point your Mobile Firefox browser to that link, install, and restart.)

What gives? Am I misreading something? Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do which won't run into this problem? Is there more extensive documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the `UIReady` event.

```
window.addEventListener("UIReady", function(){your code}, false);
```

Comment: That did it. (Although I don't seem to be able to get at the window which fires the event, either through `event.originalTarget` or, more distressingly, through a closure. Got around this with a global variable, for now; not such a big deal when there's only the one window.)

I have to ask, though: How did you learn how to do that?

Comment: From the [usual source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/chrome/content/browser.js#280) :-)